# How do I determine the architecture of an executable binary on Windows 10

Tags: windows, cpu-architecture, portable-executable, identification

Given some `Random.exe` on Windows, how can I determine

1. its CPU architecture eg Intel/ARM, and
2. its bitness eg 32 or 64.

Is there a property in File Explorer, some other tool, or programatic method I can use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The architecture of the executable is written in the Machine field of the COFF header. You can retrieve it programatically or manually with a hex editor:

- Go to offset 0x3C in the file. The four bytes there hold the offset of the COFF header (from the beginning of the file).
- Go to the COFF header pointed by the above field, and advance by four (4) bytes.
- The following two (2) bytes are the Machine field.

You can see PE structure [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1b/Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG_fixed.svg). The valid Machine field values are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#machine-types).

**EDIT:** Here's a C code that does that, untested:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    uint32_t offset = 0;
    fseek(f, 0x3c, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&offset, sizeof(offset), 1, f);
    fseek(f, offset + 4, SEEK_SET);
    uint16_t machine = 0;
    fread(&machine, sizeof(machine), 1, f);
    printf("Machine: 0x%.4x\n", machine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, edited question to include programatic methods.

Answer (score 12):

[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) **`file foo.exe`** will identify file contents based on their file format magic numbers / metadata.  (Not their filenames).  Presumably also available or installable from source in [MinGW](https://www.cygwin.com/), and probably comes with any of the distros for [MS's Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10), WSL.

This is the same open-source implementation of [the POSIX `file` command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/file.html) that most BSD and all Linux distros use. The upstream source is https://www.darwinsys.com/file/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command) shows example output.  And I have a couple Windows executables on my Linux desktop:

```
peter@volta:~/.wine/drive_c$ file Program\ Files/Internet\ Explorer/iexplore.exe 
..../iexplore.exe: PE32+ executable (GUI) x86-64, for MS Windows

peter@volta:~/.wine/drive_c$ file Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/The\ Master\ Genealogist\ v9/tmg9.exe 
..../tmg9.exe: PE32 executable (GUI) Intel 80386, for MS Windows
```

IDK if this is the *best* answer, if you don't regularly use a command line shell (like I do on my Linux desktop).

---

`file` works for pretty much any kind of file, e.g. ZIP, JPG, mp4, mkv, and for widely-used file formats it will even grab some extra metadata like JPG image resolution.  (It's not based on filename, it opens the file to look at the metadata.  Usually the first 4 bytes or so are a "magic number" that indicate what kind of file.)

For plain text formats, it can sometimes use heuristics to distinguish HTML vs. plain text, and recognize UTF-8 vs. UTF-16 vs. ISO-8851 vs. plain ASCII, and DOS vs. Unix line endings, etc.  Pretty nice program to have around, not just for executables.

Comment: Indeed, with WSL installed, `wsl file some.exe` works as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
dumpbin /headers
```

will also show the CPU architecture and the large address aware state of an executable, this tool is shipped with Visual Studio and gives the following output:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.11.25547.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file C:\Users\justins\projects\random.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               4 number of sections
        5C0BB424 time date stamp Sat Dec  8 04:08:04 2018
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
              22 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
```

Comment: Fortunately, they put both properties are on the same line.  `dumpbin /headers | findstr /i machine` works in a script.

Answer (score 1):

I made a CLI utility for this called [pearch](https://github.com/oxou/pearch)

Posting here as it may be handy for newcomers.

It was initially written in PHP which you can still see in the [deprecated-php-version](https://github.com/oxou/pearch/tree/deprecated-php-version) branch but I've ported it to C.

On Linux you must compile yourself, for Windows you can use [pre-built binaries](https://github.com/oxou/pearch/releases).

---

Usage:

```
C:\> pearch c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe c:\windows\syswow64\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe: Architecture: amd64
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe: Architecture: i386
```

Answer (score -3):

A very easy way to do this with JavaScript: https://github.com/doctolib/windows-binary-architecture

```js
getTargetArch(yourFilePath, (err, archName, archCode) => {
  // you can check arch name here
}
```