# Getting machine information of an executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, architecture, executable, platform

I have different c++ executable files compiled for different architectures(x86_64,arm32 etc) with different names in a folder inside my python3 project. I would be using one of these when i run the project on the corresponding architecture. Currently I change the path of the executable file before running in various architectures. 
Could someone suggest me the way to :

- find the machine architecture info (whether arm32,x86 etc)  of these executable or get the executable
  compiled for the architecture in which the code is running or In
  which machine or architecture is the each of these executable is
  complied.

I tried to check the platform library in python,but i didn't get any valid solution . How do i achieve any one the above in Python3

Answer (score 0):

To find the architecture of the current platform, you want [`uname`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.uname) from the `platform` lib:

```
import platform

uname = platform.uname()
uname.machine

'x86_64'
```

**EDIT:** To find the target architecture of a compiled binary is more difficult. There's always an OS call to tell you if the binary was compiled to run on a particular architecture for that OS, but no easy find to find the compilation target of an arbitrary binary. Here are a few things you can do, depending on what platform you're on:

- On Linux, you can use the util `file`: https://linux.die.net/man/1/file
- On macOS, you can use the BSD util `file`: https://ss64.com/osx/file.html
- Windows binaries encode their target in a header: [How do I determine the architecture of an executable binary on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54834984/how-do-i-determine-the-architecture-of-an-executable-binary-on-windows-10)

Here's an example from macOS:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(['file', '/bin/cat'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result.stdout.decode("utf-8").strip().split(' ')

['/bin/cat:', 'Mach-O', '64-bit', 'executable', 'x86_64']
```

Comment: No, this is to get the system platform. But, i would like to pick one executable from multiple executable's which is compiled for one architecture? How do i get that ? How do i know which executable is  compiled for which architecture

Comment: It's not simple, but can be done. Take a look at my edit.

Comment: I'd start with magic numbers for starters always appearing as first bytes in the executable. `MZ` for Windows/DOS, `ELF` for Linux, `FEEDFACF`/`FEEDFACE` for MacOS

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the bash command `file`, example:

```
$ file myExecutable

myExecutable: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), 
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, 
BuildID[sha1]=3c3776317ac80168ec7fb9b095e59c4ae256b6a5, for 
GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped`
```